# Getting images by parsing constantly changing HTML

Tags: iphone, ios5, html-parsing, image

I'm in the process of developing an iOS app that retrieves images from a URL (http://m.9gag.com). It so happens that the HTML for the URL is in constant change and whenever I have a working code, the site's style changes.

Is there any way I could pull those images from the HTML without having to worry about webpage changes? There is no public API at the moment so that's sadly not an option.

I look forward to hearing some options.

Also, if the page is set so that when the user scrolls to the bottom, it loads more content, how can I get more html to load based on how far down in the HTML parsing I've got? I'm not using a webview, I just need to update the HTML I initially retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the simplest way in your case - use regular expression (for example `http://[A-Za-z0-9_/\.]*\.jpg`) to extract URLs and keep track of already pulled images.

Comment: Thanks for that. What can I do if the site has infinite scrolling in order to get the images that follow after the initial load has been parsed? Can I load the rest of the HTML somehow?